# Model selection for mixed effects models based on AIC

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I would like to fit a mixed effects model and get a list of the top ten candidate models ranked by AIC. For fixed effects models, I use the `glmulti:glmulti` function to fit the model and the `glmulti:weightable` function to get a list of candidate models ranked by AIC, which gives this output:

```
##                              model     aicc      weights
## 1          outcome ~ 1 + ist + hwt 188.3154 0.6044616289
## 2 outcome ~ 1 + ist + hwt + troadn 190.3552 0.2179837514
## 3                outcome ~ 1 + hwt 191.7862 0.1065837756
## 4       outcome ~ 1 + hwt + troadn 193.5704 0.0436764670
## 5                outcome ~ 1 + ist 195.8793 0.0137685009
## 6       outcome ~ 1 + ist + troadn 196.3339 0.0109688767
## 7             outcome ~ 1 + troadn 200.0687 0.0016949662
## 8                      outcome ~ 1 201.4210 0.0008620334
```

Is there an equivalent package to complete these same steps with a mixed effects model? I used the `lme4::glmer` function to fit a mixed effects model, but this does not produce a list of top models based on AIC score. Is there an alternate function/package, or is this process not used with mixed effects models?

I would like to get a list of top 10 candidate models for:

```
(outcome ~ sex + season + year  + (1 | obsname) + (1 | bird), data = detect, family = binomial)
```

Comment: You can do stepwise selection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55638476/how-to-do-stepwise-model-with-random-effect-lme4-lmertest ; I don't know if there is an analogue of all-subsets for random effect possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

- `MuMIn::dredge()` will fit all subsets of the *fixed-effect* component of a mixed model (`?"MuMin-models"` gives a complete list, including `lmer` and `glmer` objects among many others).
- `lmerTest::step()` will do backward stepwise reduction (but not all-subsets fitting) of `lmer` models (but not `glmer` models). There is some discussion of/guidance on stepwise model reduction in the vignettes of the [repsychling package](https://github.com/dmbates/RePsychLing) (on GitHub), but not software to do it automatically.
- `LMERConvenienceFunctions::ffRanefLMER.fnc()` does *forward* selection of random effects components.

I am not aware of any machinery to do automatic all-subsets evaluation of the random effects component of mixed models in R (which doesn't mean it doesn't exist ...)